# Designer to see internals?

Tags: c#, assemblies, designer, strongname

I have my signed assemblies here, in one of them I have a picture in the resources.
The other one is granted to use it as it's own, so my other assembly can reference the picture, and everything works fine.

---

Only if it wouldn't be for the Form Designer in VS2008.
It does not see the Image. ( It might be ok, since it's linked at compile time. One would think!!! )

---

BUT it does see these pictures if pictures are manually modified from `internal` to `public`.
The resources class still remains internal. Then it works.
( It because it's the same namespace. )
The resource class is not partial, since partial only works in the same assembly, thus it helps not.

---

The Problem is: those resources are internal for a reason, I do not want to reuse them from unsigned assemblies, and even more do not want others outside the team do so.

Any suggestions?

Thx in advance

Comment: The solution I choose was to let those Images be public in Debug mode, while stay internal on release.

#if DEBUG
public
#else
internal
#endif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem when attempting to bind Silverlight XAML controls to text from resource files.  The parser was unable to see the resource because the default Visual Studio resource generator creates the class as `internal` even when `public` was selected from the drop-down.

In my case, installing the custom resource generator tool from [here](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/name/archive/2007/10/16/Public-Strongly-Typed-Resource-Generator.aspx) generated the class as `public`, allowing the parser to access it.  Perhaps it would allow the designer to do the same?

Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem is that, I do not want my stuff to be public. However this gave me an idea to write my own tool for that.